# Unable to use Fragments with Android Compatibility Package

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

In ["Fragments for All"](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html), Xavier Ducrohet, Android SDK Tech Lead says Google releases an Android Compatibility Package by SDK Manager.

I've installed it, but, how can I use it now?

How can I integrate Android Compatibility Package in my project?

Comment: I solved it! I need to use Honeycomb sdk, thank you!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you're using version 12 or later of the Eclipse Android support library, just right-click on your project, and choose Android Tools > Add Compatibility Library...

Answer (score 14):

There is a .jar file called `android-support-v4.jar` in the directory `{yoursdkpath}/extras/android/compatibility/v4/`. Copy this into your libs folder in the root of your project and add the file to the build path in Eclipse.

Comment: i did that and it still doesnt work. Im trying to run API Demo sample on my android 2.2 device. I even tried copying the support.jar file into the samples directory..

Answer (score 4):

Premier,

I followed the Fragments example on the [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html) to create a "backwards" compatible app using Fragments. In the article there is a brief mention of the Main activity that uses a layout with fragments.

> The code for this activity is not interesting; it just calls setContentView() with the given layout:

What should be mentioned here is that this activity must derive from FragmentActivity and not Activity class. This threw me off for a while.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Refer [Using Fragment of Android Compatibility Package](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-fragment-of-android-compatibility.html) may help you

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Step 2: Configuring the Build Path" Section [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/)

Answer (score -1):

This is easy with new Eclipse I downloaded. Provided you have all the paths for SDK etc setup correctly, Right click on Project -> Android tools-> and Hit "Add compatibility Library" it will add the JAR file

Comment: How is that different to James Moore's answer?