# Can I create a statich part of view

Tags: android

I`m wondering about one thing. If I decide to have a part of my View same in every Intent. For example 2 buttons at the bottom of screen and for example I have 3 diffrent views, List, Detail and a third one :) Do I need to put the buttons on every xml schem for each view or can I create other xml and attach it in each activity with all listener etc.

If I can attach in activity how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a XML buttons.xml with the common elements

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">      
<ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_title_search"
            android:onClick="myHandle" />
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/myButton2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_title_search"
            android:onClick="myHandle" />

</merge>
```

Include it in another xml:

```
<include layout="@layout/buttons"/>
```

where **buttons** is the name of the xml file to be included

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<include />` tag in your XML files.

See [Layout Tricks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate layout for your buttons then in the layout you wish to display them use the include tag.

This will allow you to reuse the same layout in multiple parent layouts.

Answer (score 1):

The include works as stated above you could also consider using fragments

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

You can use these in older versions of Android by including the compatibility library in your application. It's definitely more work than a simple include but if you need some reusable UI for more sophisticated features than simple buttons you might want to look at that as well

[How to use compatibility API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195697/unable-to-use-fragmentation-api-with-android-compatibility-package)