# Error during creating jar file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I d' like to create a jar file. In Eclipse I go to file -> Export. But, unfortunately I get an error:

> ... is not on its project's build path. Unable to get package fragment root...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195697/unable-to-use-fragments-with-android-compatibility-package

Answer (score 0):

I think you might miss a JAR that you're using through imports, you've to fix your Java build path.

To do that, right click on the project, choose Properties, select `Java Build Path`, click on Libraries tab, Add JARs, add the missing JAR.

If it doesn't work try to restart Eclipse as well and give us a little more context.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same error while exporting prepared class files through .jardesc (stored export description). Export was adding a lot of prepared class files (so no source .java files) to jar. Due to some changes to java build path source files have been added next to prepared class files. This caused that export did not use given class files. Removing source files fixed error. I had to fix java build path then to prevent source files appearing next to prepared class files again.