# Android Master Layout Templating

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hi am am working on android.

I have a layout which was used in every activity.

I mean I have a layout which has footer and header.

On each activity, header and footer same and has same actions.

[image: As you see,]

I want to use a general layout for header and footer.

I mean in a activity, I will put the content area layout to general layout.

I find someting but not enough.

How can I do this?

Is there a dummy docuument for do this?.

sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 4):

What you are talking about is a new Android design pattern called Fragments. Since 3.0 fragments are small activity like views that can be combined to form a screen.

So you would create a Header and Footer fragment and then include these across all activities that require them.

The other pattern you might want to look at is the Action bar pattern, which is used to place a bar at the top of screens with common content and functions, similar to your header.

Also another way would be using xml files to define your header and footer then instantiate these as views in code and add them programmatically to your content views xml definition. The problem with this is that the code behind the header and footer would need to be replicated in each controller. Your best bet is using Fragments, I'll put some useful links below:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710573/need-a-fragments-example

Comment: I am using android 2.1 version

Comment: Then use the android compatibility package. Android is designed in such a way that it is easy enough to design an app for 4.0 then quickly re-engineer it for previous versions using the package. If you don't use Fragments then it will be nearly impossible to refactor to use fragments later on, I know from experience on that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195697/unable-to-use-fragments-with-android-compatibility-package

Comment: what about rhis code ?
http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2011/01/08/ldquomaster-pagesrdquo-in-android.aspx

Comment: Its a grand idea but fragments give you more power. My app is a Train Timetable app. So my main screen has fragments for header, main functions (buttons like search, map, stations etc), favourites, nearby arrivals, nearby departures, and twitter train delay notifications. Depending on how big the screen is I dynamically hide certain fragments so the screen is useful at all levels, other fragments are then put in other screens.

Comment: Another benefit of fragments is reusability. The idea is each fragment does something like display your favourites or provide a header. Then to reuse all you need to do is import the fragment, without any major code duplication. So each fragment is a self contained block of UI and code together. Really pretty damn useful

Answer (score 2):

You could use includes for the header & footer or add them dynamically from a base class, but I think a better approach is to use a single Activity to host the app, and then use Fragments for your screen content.

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html

Comment: I am using android 2.1 version

Comment: That isn't a problem. Fragments are included in the compatibility package for Android (look in the SDK Manager) so you can easily use Fragments in pre-v3.0 versions of Android. Further than that you could use www.ActionBarSherlock.com which is a library that (in addition to Fragments) also provides the ActionBar

Comment: http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2011/01/08/ldquomaster-pagesrdquo-in-android.aspx this code not using fragments. is it problem ?

Comment: Android isn't ASP.NET. I see no reason not to use Fragments, that's what they're for.

Comment: I'll try to compatible package. 
is it support everything in v4 ?

Comment: for example popup menu. Can ı use popup menu in version 2.1 with compatible package ?

Comment: If you use ABS on an older version, the menu functionality is the same as on that version of Android, so the menu appears at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I have nothing against fragments, and Yes, they're the way to go, but for the beginner android developer, you can do achieve what you're trying to do with `<include>`s and base activities.

This [article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) explains nicely the use of `<include>`s, but to sum it up, you can have a layout xml file that you can "include" to another layout, instead of rewriting the same stuff over and over.

For the functionality of the headers and footers (assuming they do something when clicked), you can create a base activity that you can extend instead of the normal android `Activity`.
Define the logic for the header and footer clicks in this base activity, such as with this sample code:

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {
...
public void onHeaderClick(View view) {
// when header is clicked, do this.
}
public void onFooterClick(View view) {
// when footer is clicked, do this.
```

In your  layout (the one you have as a separate xml), add an `onClick` attribute to your header/footer, assigning the name of the method in the base activity.

such as

```
android:onClick="onHeaderClick"
```

Then it's just a matter of extending MyBaseActivity for all your activities that have headers and footers.

Comment: @Josepus: I am not implementing any thing asked in this question. But I liked your concept of BaseActivity. Do you have any links regarding your concept? Because thinking about your concept brought some doubts in my mind.

Comment: it's actually a self-discovered idea, but similar solutions (or rather, the same exact solution) came up when i was reading on stackoverflow about the same problem. (no links though. try searching for "android base activity") the important thing is, it works :)

Answer (score -1):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) out, you can indeed reuse your layout whenever you want it to.