# support library for fragments

Tags: android, sdk

I want to install support library to use fragments.

I found 2 solution

solution 1:

[image]

problem:

[image]

solution 2:

[Unable to use Fragments with Android Compatibility Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195697/unable-to-use-fragments-with-android-compatibility-package#answers-header)

problem:

i get this in the console:

```
[2012-08-16 13:49:12 - Android Compatibility JAR not found:] C:\Documents and Settings\user\v4\android-support-v4.jar]
```

How to install the support library?

Thank You

Comment: i am trying to run it on Emulator using api 10(2.3.3)...but in manifest i have min sdk = "4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Download `android-support-v4.jar` file put or copy it in libs folder
>   of  project and then Right Click on that jar file - > Build Project ->
>   Add to build path.

Download jar file from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidsupportv4jar.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Download using solution 1.

You'll find the JAR file in `\android-sdk\extras\android\compatibility\v4`.

**How to use it:**

In your project, create a new folder called: `libs`.

Copy the library and paste it into the `libs` folder.

Comment: but the problem with solution 1 is i cannot find any option as "support library" in the Eclipse > Window > Android SDK Manae > Extras

Comment: Did you update Android SDK tools/platform-tools and ADT plugin ?